# GridView Showing Same screen for all Items

Tags: android, gridview

In Gridview, when am selecting an item its going to same page. but i need to go different pages according to icon name (For Eg. when am clicking Icon CARS It should go CARS Page having details.)

Here is my java class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programlist, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Education.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position", position);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
                //Add the position to the intent to be used in the second activity.

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

what changes i should make ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need onItemClick and onItemClickListener.